# An elegant way of creating a Scala sequence that comprises lagged tuples

Tags: scala, tuples, seq

I want to create a Scala sequence comprising tuples. The input is a text file like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to construct "lagged" tuples like this:

```
(A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, E)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using the `tail` and `zip`:

```
val xs = Seq('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
xs zip xs.tail
```

If efficiency is a concern (i.e. you don't want to create an extra intermediate sequence by calling `tail` and the `Seq` you use are not `List`s, meaning that `tail` takes O(n)) then you can use views:

```
xs zip xs.view.tail
```

Comment: If the `Seq` is actually a `List` then `xs zip xs.tail` is quite efficient.

Comment: Exactly - should be more efficient than using views in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure how elegant it is, but this will work for at least all lists of more than 1 element:

```
val l = List('A,'B,'C,'D,'E,'F)
val tupled = l.sliding(2).map{case x :: y :: Nil => (x,y)}

tupled.toList
// res8: List[(Symbol, Symbol)] = List(('A,'B), ('B,'C), ('C,'D), ('D,'E), ('E,'F))
```

If you want something more elegant than that, I'd advise you look at [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for nice ways to convert between lists and tuples.

Comment: Actually, @axel22's answer is much, much nicer than mine! Leaving it here for information only.

Comment: `sliding` (without your mapping code) produces lists instead of tuples, which might be also okay. Is `l.sliding(2).toList` then the better choice compared to `l zip l.tail`?